# Why generic T is inferred as a literal type only when it has a constraint?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

See the following snippet

```
declare function foo<T>(a: T): (b: T) => boolean;

foo(111)(222);       // T inferred as 'number'
foo('hello')('bye'); // T inferred as 'string'

declare function bar<T extends number | string>(a: T): (b: T) => boolean;

bar(111)(222);       // T inferred as '111'
bar('hello')('bye'); // T inferred as 'hello'
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20function%20foo%3CT%3E(a%3A%20T)%3A%20(b%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0A%0Afoo(111)(222)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20T%20inferred%20as%20'number'%0Afoo('hello')('bye')%3B%20%2F%2F%20T%20inferred%20as%20'string'%0A%0Adeclare%20function%20bar%3CT%20extends%20number%20%7C%20string%3E(a%3A%20T)%3A%20(b%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0A%0Abar(111)(222)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20T%20inferred%20as%20'111'%0Abar('hello')('bye')%3B%20%2F%2F%20T%20inferred%20as%20'hello'%0A%0A)

As you can see the `bar` function infers the type of `T` as a literal type (`'111'` and `'hello'` in the example) but in the function `foo` they are inferred as `number` or `string`, and the only difference is the constraint.

Curiously, if use the boxed types as follows

```
declare function baz<T extends Number | String>(a: T): (b: T) => boolean;
```

then `T` is inferred as `number` and `string`, but it's enough that one of them be a primitive type and `T` is inferred as a literal type:

```
declare function brr<T extends Number | string>(a: T): (b: T) => boolean;
```

**So the question is:** Why `foo('hello')` infers `T` as `string` but `bar('hello')` infers `T` as `'hello'`? Why it happens only when `T` is constrained (in this example at least)?

Comment: When you say "why", are you asking for the reasoning behind it, or are you asking what mechanic in TypeScript causes it to happen?

Comment: By the way, it seems like `Number | string` inferring numeric literals might be a bug. It hardly seems that something inconsistent like that would be "by design".

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I thought the same when testing `Number | String`, but since every value can be _coerced_ (sort of in strict-mode) to the wrapped object then a numeric literal type is indeed assignable to ´Number´. Besides, both types will be (mostly) indistinguishable inside the function. As a reference this also works `const n: Number = 42`. It seems weird nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, you want exact literal type `'hello'` inferred for string literal `'hello'`. Sometimes, you want wider, non-specific `string` type inferred for string literal `'hello'`.

The rules - when exact type should be inferred, and when the type should be widened - went through a couple of iterations, the current implemenation [is presented here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676):

> During type argument inference for a call expression the type inferred for a type parameter T is widened to its widened literal type if:
>
> - all inferences for T were made to top-level occurrences of T within the particular parameter type, and
> - T has no constraint or its constraint does not include primitive or literal types, and
> - T was fixed during inference or T does not occur at top-level in the return type.