# able to generate TypeScript tuple from unrelated type?

Tags: typescript

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/jcalz/381562d282ebaa9b41217d1b31e2c211#gistcomment-2636999) interesting tuple trick, which basically does the following:

```
export type Lit = string | number | boolean | undefined | null | void | {};
export const tuple = <T extends Lit[]>(...args: T) => args;

const arr = tuple(1, 2, 3, 'hello', new Date, false)
// typeof arr is [1, 2, 3, 'hello', Date, false]
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Lit%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20undefined%20%7C%20null%20%7C%20void%20%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Aexport%20const%20tuple%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Lit%5B%5D%3E(...args%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20args%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20arr%20%3D%20tuple(1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%20'hello'%2C%20new%20Date%2C%20false)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20typeof%20arr%20is%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%20'hello'%2C%20Date%2C%20false%5D%0D%0A))

However, if I change the definition of `Lit`, it still works:

```
export type Lit = symbol | {};
export const tuple = <T extends Lit[]>(...args: T) => args;

const arr = tuple(1, 2, 3, 'hello', new Date, false)
// typeof arr is [1, 2, 3, 'hello', Date, false]
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Lit%20%3D%20symbol%20%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Aexport%20const%20tuple%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Lit%5B%5D%3E(...args%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20args%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20arr%20%3D%20tuple(1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%20'hello'%2C%20new%20Date%2C%20false)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20typeof%20arr%20is%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%20'hello'%2C%20Date%2C%20false%5D%0D%0A))

or if I set `Lit` to

```
export type Lit = '' | {};
```

it still works! ([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Lit%20%3D%20''%20%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Aexport%20const%20tuple%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Lit%5B%5D%3E(...args%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20args%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20arr%20%3D%20tuple(1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%20'hello'%2C%20new%20Date%2C%20false)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20typeof%20arr%20is%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%20'hello'%2C%20Date%2C%20false%5D%0D%0A))

But if I change Lit to something else like

```
export type Lit = undefined | {};
```

then I get a different resulting type for `arr`:

```
const arr = tuple(1, 2, 3, 'hello', new Date, false)
// typeof arr is [number, number, number, string, Date, boolean]
```

([playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Lit%20%3D%20undefined%20%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Aexport%20const%20tuple%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Lit%5B%5D%3E(...args%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20args%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20arr%20%3D%20tuple(1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%20'hello'%2C%20new%20Date%2C%20false)%0D%0A%2F%2F%20typeof%20arr%20is%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%2C%20number%2C%20string%2C%20Date%2C%20boolean%5D%0D%0A))

What's going on here?

Comment: Not sure what to title this question. What other tags can I add?

Comment: That's because anything (except `null` or `undefined`) is structurally compatible with `{}`. If you're looking for how to eliminate primitives - you can use `object` type instead of `{}`

Comment: Typescript does not infer literal types except in special situations. One such case is when the generic constraint is for a type that can have literal types. I'm sure @jcalz will soon post the link and a detailed explanation,  it's his original comment on github and he probably has more insight on the matter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why generic T is inferred as a literal type only when it has a constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111308/why-generic-t-is-inferred-as-a-literal-type-only-when-it-has-a-constraint)